# Adding and removing events and methods in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

In an ES6 class, if I add and remove an event like so:

```
viewer.addEventListener(
    SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
    (e) => this.onFoo(e));

viewer.removeEventListener(
    SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
    (e) => this.onFoo(e));
```

The event is added, but it isn't being removed, but if add the events like so:

in the constructor:

```
   this.onFooHandler = (e) => this.onFoo(e);
```

and add and remove them:

```
viewer.addEventListener(
    SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
    this.onFooHandler);

viewer.removeEventListener(
    SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,
    this.onFooHandler);
```

They're added and removed just fine, but why is that? What's the difference?

Notes:

I use Babel to transpile the code.

`viewer` is some object that has events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(e) => this.onFoo(e)` is an expression that always creates a new function.

```
((e) => this.onFoo(e)) === ((e) => this.onFoo(e)) // false
```

You need to maintain a handle for the original function.

```
const foo = (e) => this.onFoo(e);
foo === foo; // true
```

Comment: Throws the error "missing: after property id" when declared within an ES6 class.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass *the exact callback function* that you registered in `addEventListener` again to `removeEventListener`. It must be the exact function, *not just one that looks like it.* Since you're using anonymous callbacks, each one is a different function. If you just create the function once and assign it to a variable, then you're using the same function in both cases.

Comment: Excellent concise explanation